# How to add animation when the view becomes visible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation, hidden

I have a `UIView` in a static `UITableViewCell`. The `view` is set to hidden in `viewDidLoad`. When a `button` gets selected, the `view` gets visible.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.myView setHidden:YES];
}

- (IBAction)myButton:(id)sender
{
    if (self.myView.hidden == YES) {
        [self.myView setHidden:NO];
    } else {
        [self.myView setHidden:YES];
    }

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        if (self.myView.hidden == YES) {
            retuen 252 - self.myView.bounds.size.height;
        } else return 252;
    }
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150;
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimention;
}
```

What happens now is, when the `button` is selected, the `view` becomes visible and the `cells` height changes **with** an animation; but the `view` gets visible right away, and it gets in the way of other objects (until the `cells` animation is over).

How can I make the `view` also enter with an animation? (I'd prefer it animate in height.)

**Edit**

I tried the following to animate the height, so that it should be synced with the `cell`

```
if (self.myView.hidden == YES) {
    [self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.myView.frame.origin.x, self.myView.frame.origin.y - self.myView.frame.size.height, self.myView.frame.size.width, self.myView.frame.size.height)];

    [self.myView setHidden:NO];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^(){
        [self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.myView.frame.origin.x, 0, self.myView.frame.size.width, self.myView.frame.size.height)];
    }];
}
```

But all it does is animates the `views` location, (from up to down,) not its height??

Answer (score 1):

You can change it like this,

```
if (self.myView.hidden == YES) {
    [self.myView setAlpha:0.0];
    [self.myView setHidden:NO];
}
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    if (self.myView.hidden == YES) {
         [self.myView setAlpha:1.0];
    } else {
         [self.myView setAlpha:0.0];
    }
}
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (self.myView.alpha == 0.0) {
        [self.myView setHidden:YES];
    }
}];
```

May this helps you.

Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: It is because you change the `y` coordinate of your `self.myview`. You can set `y` as it is, and Just increase the height as you required.

Answer (score 1):

Inside myButton: event you can use

```
- (IBAction)myButton:(id)sender
{

    if (self.myView.hidden == YES) {
        [self.myView setHidden:NO];
    } else {
        [self.myView setHidden:YES];
    }

   [self.myView setAlpha:0.0f];
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:nil
                     animations:^{
                         [self.myView setAlpha:1.0f];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL complete){
                         [self.myView setAlpha:1.0f];
                     }];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

If you want to animate the height of the view, you can do as-

```
CGFloat viewHeight = self.myView.frame.size.height;
    [self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.myView.frame.origin.x, self.myView.frame.origin.y, self.myView.frame.size.width, 0)];
           [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                  delay:0.0
                                options:nil
                             animations:^{
                                 [self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.myView.frame.origin.x, self.myView.frame.origin.y, self.myView.frame.size.width, viewHeight)];
                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL complete){
                                 [self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.myView.frame.origin.x, self.myView.frame.origin.y, self.myView.frame.size.width, viewHeight)];
                             }];
```

Comment: Just tried that, and it doesn't animate. (By the way, I'm using a `UIDatePicker`)

Comment: have you initialized the viewHeight as CGFloat viewHeight = self.myView.frame.size.height;

Answer (score 0):

the hidden property on a UIView is not animatable, you will need to unhide it, then set it to a state that it should be in as the animation is about to start (so maybe set alpha = 0, or height = 0) then in the animation block, set it to it correct state you want it to be in (alpha = 1, height = cell.frame.size.height)

eg

```
view.hidden = NO;
view.alpha = 0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^() {
    view.alpha = 1;
}];
```

Comment: with regards to your edit, you are simply changing the y position of the views frame and not the height, the last parameter of the `CGRectMake` is the height

Answer (score 0):

//Show

```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
                              delay:0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^{
                             viewtemp.alpha = 0.912f;
                         } completion:NULL];
```

//hide

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.9f
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         viewtemp.alpha = 0.0f;
                     } completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

@arnold, you are tried to change its `Y Position`, instead of `height`, you need to applied animation on its `Height`. like as belowed.

```
if (self.myView.hidden == YES) {
[self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.myView.frame.origin.x, 0, self.myView.frame.size.width, 0)];

[self.myView setHidden:NO];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^(){
    [self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.myView.frame.origin.x, 0, self.myView.frame.size.width, self.myView.frame.size.height)];
}];
}
```

Comment: @Arnold, can you please check that what is `UIView's` height?